# Running alpine docker container deployed to Azure App Service does not respond to pings after deployment

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, port, .net-6.0, alpine-linux

I am trying to deploy a docker image running a C# .Net 6 Web API to an Azure App Service (for containers). The service currently works using `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0` base image but I want to change to `alpine:3.19`. The updated docker file looks like this:

```
# Build Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY MyProject/MyProject.csproj ./MyProject/

RUN dotnet restore MyProject/MyProject.csproj

COPY MyProject/* ./MyProject/

RUN dotnet publish --configuration Release --output out MyProject/MyProject.csproj

# Unit Test Runner

FROM build as unit-tests

WORKDIR /app/MyProject.UnitTests

COPY MyProject.UnitTests/. .

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "test"]

# Integration Test Runner

FROM build as integration-tests

WORKDIR /app/MyProject.IntegrationTests

COPY MyProject.IntegrationTests/. .

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "test"]

# Run Stage
FROM alpine:3.19
RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache dotnet6-runtime \
    && apk add --no-cache  aspnetcore6-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
# Allow SSH access
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/
RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache bash \
    && apk add --no-cache openssh \
    && apk add --no-cache tini \
    && apk add --no-cache netcat-openbsd \
    && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd \
    && chmod u+x ./entrypoint.sh \
    && cd /etc/ssh/ \
    && ssh-keygen -A

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 2222

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]

CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
#--- Starting SSH
/usr/sbin/sshd
exec dotnet MyProject.dll
```

When I deploy to the app service the container starts up. I can tell this from the logs which show a background service running. The issue is that the container seems to be inaccessible via port 80. The web app start up process gives off logs like this:

> Waiting for response to warmup request for container
> app_my-project_1_3addd53d. Elapsed time =
> 30.5399342 sec

Before eventually failing:

> 2023-12-13T02:18:20.920Z ERROR - Container
> app_my-project_1_3addd53d didn't respond
> to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for
> debugging. 2023-12-13T02:18:20.970Z INFO  - Stopping site
> app_my-project_1 because it failed during
> startup.

I have tried setting the following appsetting:

```
WEBSITES_PORT = 80
```

It has not made a difference. From the logs I can see it is the following docker command which is run:

```
docker run -d --expose=80 --name app_my-project_1_3addd53d -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=false -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=app_my-project -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=app_my-project.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=2f7d09e6f18b384667ff962cc75fe4cbeb8ff744d3ba3c5cc3766bd82eb68007 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 myregistry.azurecr.io/app_my-project:tag
```

Comment: Enable **Application Logging** in `Azure App Service=>App Service Logs` and check the error logs in `Azure App Service=>Log Stream`.

Comment: @Pravallika-KV Application logging is already enabled. In the log stream I can see that the service has started and is running successfully due to the normal logging of a background service (an implementation of `IHostedService`). The container has started up successfully. The issue is that despite `EXPOSE 80` in the Dockerfile, the API does not appear to be accessible over that or any other port. As part of the App Service start up process it pings that port to ensure that the service has started up. As it cannot get a response, it then tries to start the service again.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

I needed to add the following to my Dockerfile:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
```